# Overlay geom_density() on geom_histogram(position = "fill")

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know how to overlay a density plot on a count histogram with ggplot2, but I can't figure it out when the position is set to fill. I also have a variable mapped to the fill aesthetic on the histogram (hence the fill position). Help would be greatly appreciated. Below is a stripped down version of my code for reference (sans the density plot):

```
assigned.data %>%
ggplot(aes(x = balance, fill = cluster)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 50000, position = "fill")
```

Edit: Initial plot added

[image: Density Histogram]

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding some of these parameters: `fill` as an aesthetic means the color filling bars or polygons, but `fill` as a position means the way a position is set so that bars go from 0 to 100%. To help you out with more detail, please post a representative sample of data for us to work with

Comment: @camille I understand that. Mapping to the fill aesthetic with the histogram position parameter set to fill creates a plot that shows the distribution of the fill variable across the different buckets of the histogram. Now, I want to overlay the overall distribution of the variable used for the histogram to be referenced when evaluating each bucket.

Comment: I would have just used a stacked count histogram, but the number of clusters mapped to the fill aesthetic is simply too large.

Comment: You want to overlay density curves of each group, or a density curve of the total values? I think you're going to need to split something, maybe facet by group, because this is already very hard to read and seems like it would only get harder.

Comment: I'm also unsure how you would have histogram bars that span a density from 0 to 1, but then show a density curve that is legible. e.g. if you're showing a density of all groups but with a fill position, wouldn't that just be a straight line? Either way, to get a lot of insight, you'll need to post a sample of data

Comment: @camille Total values. Should just be a gaussian-like density curve with size and color changed for visibility. I agree this is not a very pretty graph, but I'm using it for EDA and am evaluating several different ways.

Comment: And I don't see why you think the density curve would be a straight line. It should be like any other density curve, a parabolic curve ranging from zero to one

Comment: If it were done with a fill position, which I can't tell if you're trying to do or not, it would be a straight line

Comment: @camille The histogram has a fill position, not the density curve. The only aesthetic needed for it would be x normally. I don't know how to combine the two plots though.